# Print only '+' or '-' if string matches (two files)

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, awk

I would like to print only a '+' o '-' symbols if string is found or not. Basically, I have two files:

Input file 1 (tab-delimited):

```
HPNK_00457
HPNK_00458
HPNK_00459
```

Input file 2 (tab-delimited):

```
HPNK_00457  AAA50325    1e-43   437 28  43  83  ATP-binding protein.
HPNK_00458  P25256  8e-43   429 28  43  82  RecName: Full=Tylosin resistance ATP-binding protein tlrC.
HPNK_00458  CAM96590    1e-42   429 27  42  87  ABC transporter ATP-binding protein [Streptomyces ambofaciens].
```

Desired output (tab-delimited, maintaining order of strings in file 1):

```
HPNK_00457 +
HPNK_00458 +
HPNK_00459 -
```

This is what I've been using up to now, but need to update:

```
while read vl; do grep "^$vl      " file2 || printf -- "- -\n" ; done < file1
```

Thanks, trying to learn everyday here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
while read -r line
do
    grep -q "$line" f2 && echo "$line +" || echo "$line -"
done < f1
```

As `grep -q` just returns true if it has matched something, in that case we print the file name + `+` otherwise, we print the file name + `-`.

It returns:

```
$ while read -r line; do grep -q "$line" f2 && echo "$line +" || echo "$line -"; done < f1
HPNK_00457 +
HPNK_00458 +
HPNK_00459 -
```

Comment: Ah! You don't need to reciprocate.  It seemed like an obvious oversight, so couldn't help editing.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } { print $1, ($1 in a ? "+" : "-" ) }' file2 file1
```

Results:

```
HPNK_00457 +
HPNK_00458 +
HPNK_00459 -
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lane'
  BEGIN{ $, ="\t"; $x=shift; @h{ map /(\S+)/, <> } =(); @ARGV=$x }
  print @F, exists $h{$F[0]} ? "+" : "-";
' file1 file2
```

output

```
HPNK_00457      +
HPNK_00458      +
HPNK_00459      -
```

Comment: The syntax `@h{ map /(\S+)/, <> } =()` looked confusing at first, but I understand it now that it's a hash slice. `%h = map{ $_->[0]++ } map[split] , <>` or `@h{ map { /(\S+)/ } <> }++` will work too. Thanks again!

Comment: @JS웃 yes it is a hash slice. Btw, `@h{..}++` only increments last value for the key. https://eval.in/133988

Comment: Good point @mpapec. I didn't see it from that angle. I guess it worked because the solution in this case only needed the existence of the key in the hash. Appreciate your help in explaining the details.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the algorithm:

1. Read file 2. For each line,
2. Get the first word
3. Store it in a hash.
4. Read file 1. For each line, chomp it, then
5. print $hash{$_}? '+' : '-'

I can write the code for you but if you want to learn everyday, it will be a useful exercise if you want to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This simple Perl script should do the work

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
## f1 and f2 are the 2 files containing your input data
open FILE1, f1;
open FILE2, f2;

@file1data = <FILE1>;
@file2data = <FILE2>;

my $row = 0;
foreach $data (@file1data) {
        chomp($data);
        if (grep (/$data/,$file2data[$row]) ) {
                print $data . " " . "+\n";
        }
        else {
                print $data . " " . "-\n";
        }
        $row++;
}
```

Comment: To me it looks like he wants to check if lines from file1 are present in file2 .. if they are present print a '+' or print '-'.  As of now my code verifies if the line from file1 has a match in exactly the same line number in file2  (that is what i interpreted the line 'maintaining order of strings in file 1' in the question ) .. if the requirement is that the line from file1 can have a corresponding entry anywhere in file2, we can easily replace the grep code with your hash suggestion. As of now, I think if i use a hash, i cannot guarantee that order is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR
     {a[$1];next}
     {b[$1]}
     END{
     for(i in a)
     if(b[i]){print i,"+"}
     else{print i,"-"}
     }' file1 file2
```

Comment: Do you think the OP will [understand](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22065228/1269037) this `awk`-based answer?